# BST insert(root, value) recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

EDIT: I've figured it out - scrapped this design and started over and it worked! Thank you for your suggestions.

I'm working on a BST algorithm homework assignment and I'm hopelessly stuck on the insert method. All of the resources I've found online have a version similar to what I've created, but I am failing the JUnit test given to us by our professor. I can pass the base cases (null root and binary tree where the root.payload == value). I can't seem to pass the next test though. Here is my code for the insert(root, value) method:

```java
public static Node<Integer> insert(Node<Integer> root, Integer value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node<>(value);
    } else if (root.payload.equals(value)) {
        return root;
    } else if (value < root.payload) {
        return root.left = insert(root.left, value);
    } else {
        return root.right = insert(root.right, value);
    }
    return root;
}
```

What ends up being returned is the *original* root node, but from my understanding, the returned value at the end should be my new node. I've looked at my textbook and some online resources and all of them have something very similar to this design, so I'm quite confused as to why it's not working. I've tried some other designs but all of them end up being a NullPointerException. The JUnit test that was given to us verifies that we inserted the node in the correct place, in addition to checking the Node's payload. I'm failing both of these tests. This is our first assignment using recursion, so I'm still fairly new at it. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the returned value from your method to be the newly inserted node , you have to add return statement in the elseIf clause as well , so that when the recursive stack unwinds it returns the new created node. Check the code below

```
public static Node<Integer> insert(Node<Integer> root, Integer value) {
if (root == null) {
    root = new Node<>(value);
} else if (value <= root.payload) {
    return root.left = insert(root.left, value);   // add a return here
} else {
   return  root.right = insert(root.right, value);  // add a return here
}
return root;
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've tried that in previous iterations and what happens is I end up failing one of the earlier tests. I'm going to update my code above to reflect the change. I still pass my base cases but fail when trying to insert a leaf node.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Node<Integer> insert(Node<Integer> root, Integer value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node<>(value);
    } else if (value < root.payload) {
         root.left = insert(root.left, value);
    } else if (value > root.payload) {
         root.right = insert(root.right, value);
    }
    return root;
}
```

This will add the value at its correct place and return the root. You can print the tree to check the same

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This version of the code is still failing the test. When I check the payload of the Node that's being returned, it's the payload of the original root Node, not the payload of the inserted Node.